# If $\langle x\rangle \subseteq\langle y\rangle $, for some $y\in R$, then either $\langle y\rangle =R$ or $\langle y\rangle =\langle x\rangle $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to prove following statement.

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $x \in R$ be an irreducible element in $R$. 
If $\langle x\rangle  \subseteq \langle y\rangle $, for some $y\in R$, then either $\langle y\rangle =R$ or $\langle y\rangle =\langle x\rangle $.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69826).

Comment: This is just the definition of irreducible element! Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ah, i see, i was confused about terminology irreducible and prime. Now i see some distinction. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\langle x\rangle \subsetneq \langle y\rangle$. Since $y-x\in \langle y \rangle$, we may write $y-x = ay$ for some $a\in R$, and so $x = y(1-a)$. $x$ is irreducible, and so either $y$ or $1-a$ is a unit.

Suppose $1-a$ is a unit, and let $b=(1-a)^{-1}$. Then $y(1-a)\in \langle x\rangle \implies y(1-a)b=y\in \langle x\rangle$, a contradiction (since if $y\in \langle x\rangle$ we have $\langle x\rangle  = \langle y\rangle$).

Therefore, $y$ is a unit, and so $\langle y\rangle = R$.