# Is $\{x f(x)+3g(x) \;|\;f,g\in \mathbb{Q}[x]\}$ a (main) ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is it possible to show whether or not 
$
\{xf(x)+3g(x)\;|\;f(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\}
$
is an ideal (or main ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$)?

I know how to prove it for $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but what with $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: Do you mean "principal" ideal = an ideal generated by onesingle element? And should it be $\;xf(x)+3g(x)\;,\;\;f,g\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $3$ is invertible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. There is thus a very simple description for your set, which will allow to answer the question directly.

Answer (score 2):

The ring $\;\Bbb F[x]\;$ is a principal ideal ring (PID) iff $\;\Bbb F\;$ is a field, so *any* ideal you find in $\;\Bbb Q[x]\;$ is principal.

OTOH, $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ is obviously not principal (since $\;\Bbb Z\;$ is not a field), so I'm not sure what you meant by " knowing to prove it in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$" .

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073631/242) for a way to prove this using only high-school algebra (evaluation of polynomials).